# Returning two or more values

Tags: java, arrays

Im learning java and i need some help on returning multiple values. I looked up ways on doing it but got confused. Hoping you guys can help me out. Im trying to make an option in the menu that allows the user to replace current jersey number with a new number and new rating. I removed other parts of the code to shorten it down a bit.  Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Roster {

final static int numArray = 5;
static int [] numJersey = new int [numArray];
static int [] numRating = new int [numArray];
static int i = 0;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    int jersey = 0;
    int newRating = 0;
    int newJersey = 0;
    char chooseOption;
    boolean quit = false;



 public static int replacePlayer(int jersey, int newJersey, int newRating){

    for(i=0; i<numArray;++i){
        if(numJersey[i]==jersey){
            numJersey[i] = newJersey;
            numRating[i] = newRating;
        }
    }

    return newJersey, newRating;
}
```

}

Comment: You mean in the `replacePlayer` method?  You're using a global array there; the values are effectively returned when you set them in the array.  (Hint #2: you don't need a loop there either.  Just set the array index to `jersey` instead of `i`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//return no value (void)
public static void replacePlayer(int jersey, int newJersey, int newRating){

        for(i=0; i<numArray;++i){
            if(numJersey[i]==jersey){
                numJersey[i] = newJersey; //numJersey newRating are class variables so they will be updated
                numRating[i] = newRating;
            }
        }
 }
```

Please note that in the code posted you don't invoke `replacePlayer`, so it has no effect.

Comment: I changed it to void and it worked but when i want to display the roster it still shows the old numbers.

Comment: after i replace a player it goes back to the menu then i enter "output roster" and it prints out the roster with the old jersey, rating numbers. The "output roster " is a for loop that prints the array.

Comment: Again:  
In the code posted you don't call `replacePlayer`

Comment: Why would i need to call replacePlayer? Shouldnt replacePlayer save the new info to the array then when ever i wanted to print the array (in another menu option) i can print the array with the new info. Or am i missing something

Comment: "Shouldnt replacePlayer save the new info to the array" - yes, if you invoke it. If you don't it does nothing. Question: do you get any compilation error if you deleted `replacePlayer` ?

Comment: I was able to get it to work. I had commented out the call replacePlayer (not sure why). Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am glad it helps. There are other correct answers like @javaguy 's . Consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the details in the array as shown below:

```
public static void replacePlayer(int jersey, int newJersey, int newRating){
  for(i=0; i<numArray;++i){
      if(numJersey[i]==jersey){
        numJersey[i] = newJersey;//replace existing jersy with new jersy
        numRating[i] = newRating;//replace existing rating with new rating
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. This should have been the accepted answer. It is similar to mine and was posted before.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return multiple value, but you can handle it by create a class that have 2 attribute, assign the attribute with appropriate value and return it. Hope this help